# How to pass an array of objects from a component in one view to a component in another view?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have this array of objects that exists in a component inside one view, that I want to access in a component inside another view. I am using Vue 3.2 with Typescript enabled.

The array of objects is as follows,

```
rideData: [{
            fromLoc: '',
            toLoc: '',
            seatNumber: '',
            waitLoc: '',
            passengers: ['', ''],
        }],....
```

I assume this would mean I have to do a child to parent, sibling to sibling, and then parent to child passing of data? I assume this would work as views are essentially just components with routes, right? However, this seems a bit complex. I have also seen suggestions with Vuex but I am not sure how it works either.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't there just be a single source of truth? If the parent is the one that hosts `rideData`, then it is just a matter of passing it down to its respective children. If the children component needs to update the state, they emit an emit to the parent that will have the responsibility of updating it. Vuex works almost the same, but instead of having the parent store the data it is just a globally accessible app state.

Comment: Either you can use Event bus or you have to use Vue store OR you need to create a service that accessible from both view.

Comment: It seems like this data ("rideData") should be persistent when you close your application - so it would be best to use localStorage (if the data is not sensitive - such as passwords) or a back-end service. You can use localStorage like: `localStorage.setItem("rideData", rideData)`. You can make it reactive by using VueUse's [useLocalStorage](https://vueuse.org/core/useLocalStorage/). If the data does not need to be persisted it would be best to use a client-side state management solution such as [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/), or Vuex, but Pinia is now the solution supported by the Vue team

Comment: I'd look to setup Pinia to share state amongst components, it is straight forward to setup, see official basic example: https://pinia.vuejs.org/introduction.html#basic-example

Comment: Turns out the answer was Pinia as everyone has had pointed out. I had tried with Vuex initially, but it was quite difficult to setup due to some issues with typescript.

Pinia worked flawlessly for this. Also, I made the object into a type for reusability. 

Thanks everyone!